# tensorflow.multiply reports shape inconsistency error, which is not present

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I was trying to implement a Deep Learning model on Python using Tensorflow. I have been facing with some issues, which are described as below:

This layer calculates the cosine distance between two vectors. I have to calculate the distance between the query and documents matrix.

```
with tf.name_scope('L1'):
    try:
        l1_par_range = np.sqrt(6.0 / (TRIGRAM_D + L1_N)) # Range for random values. Set empirically.
        weight1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([TRIGRAM_D, L1_N], -l1_par_range, l1_par_range)) # The weight matrix. shape = TRIGRAM_D X L1_N
        bias1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([L1_N], -l1_par_range, l1_par_range)) # Bias matrix. shape L1_N X 1.
        variable_summaries(weight1, 'L1_weights')
        variable_summaries(bias1, 'L1_biases')

        # query_l1 = tf.matmul(tf.to_float(query_batch),weight1)+bias1
        query_l1 = tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(query_batch, weight1) + bias1 # WX + B
        # doc_l1 = tf.matmul(tf.to_float(doc_batch),weight1)+bias1
        doc_l1 = tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(doc_batch, weight1) + bias1 # WX + B.

        query_l1_out = tf.nn.relu(query_l1) # activated output
        doc_l1_out = tf.nn.relu(doc_l1) # activated output
    except:
        print("L1")

with tf.name_scope('L2'):
    try:
        l2_par_range = np.sqrt(6.0 / (L1_N + L2_N))

        weight2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([L1_N, L2_N], -l2_par_range, l2_par_range))
        bias2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([L2_N], -l2_par_range, l2_par_range))
        variable_summaries(weight2, 'L2_weights')
        variable_summaries(bias2, 'L2_biases')

        query_l2 = tf.matmul(query_l1_out, weight2) + bias2
        doc_l2 = tf.matmul(doc_l1_out, weight2) + bias2
        query_y = tf.nn.relu(query_l2) # Query output of layer 2
        doc_y = tf.nn.relu(doc_l2) # Document output of layer 2
    except:
        print("L2")

with tf.name_scope('FD_rotate'):
    try:
        # Rotate FD+ to produce 50 FD-
        temp = tf.tile(doc_y, [1, 1]) # What is it's use?
        # tf.tile(doc_y, [1, 1]) just replicates doc_y once. Making temp equal to doc_y

        for i in range(NEG):
            rand = int((random.random() + i) * BS / NEG) # BS/NEG is a constant
            # print(rand, BS - rand)
            # print(tf.slice(temp, [rand, 0], [BS - rand, -1]))
            # print(tf.slice(temp, [0, 0], [rand, -1]))
            # print(doc_y)
            doc_y = tf.concat([doc_y,
                               tf.slice(temp, [rand, 0], [BS - rand, -1]),
                               tf.slice(temp, [0, 0], [rand, -1])], 0)
            # AP: TODO: Concatenates the matrices in the zeroeth dimension. Function depreciated. Change this!
            # AP: Shuffles the data and enlarges it.
            # first iter: doc_y
            # second iter: doc_y + doc_y[0, rand][:] + doc_y[rand:BS-rand][:]
            # ... NEG iters.
    except:
        print("OWO")

with tf.name_scope('Cosine_Similarity'):
    # Cosine similarity

    try:
        query_norm = tf.tile(tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(query_y), 1, True)), [NEG + 1, 1])
        doc_norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(doc_y), 1, True))

        print(tf.tile(query_y, [NEG + 1, 1]).get_shape().as_list())
        print(doc_y.get_shape().as_list())
        print(query_y.get_shape().as_list())
        # print(query_norm.get_shape().as_list())
        # print(doc_norm.get_shape().as_list())
        prod_first =  tf.tile(query_y, [NEG + 1, 1])

        prod_temp = tf.multiply(prod_first, doc_y)
        prod = tf.reduce_sum(prod_temp, axis = 1, keepdims = True) #Changed to False.
        print("AAAAAA")
        norm_prod = tf.multiply(query_norm, doc_norm)

        cos_sim_raw = tf.truediv(prod, norm_prod)
        cos_sim = tf.transpose(tf.reshape(tf.transpose(cos_sim_raw), [NEG + 1, BS])) * 20
    except:
        print("Some exception in Cosine similarity")
```

However, when I run the whole code, I get an error like this:

```
2019-02-05 22:02:03.674482: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
Loading data from HDD to memory: 0.00s
[52224, 120]
[52224, 120]
AAAAAA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Train data 1/9 is loaded in 0.00s
0.00% EpochTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/major/Documents/DSSMStuff/DSSM/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1334, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/major/Documents/DSSMStuff/DSSM/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1319, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/home/major/Documents/DSSMStuff/DSSM/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1407, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [51000,120] vs. [52224,120]
     [[{{node Cosine_Similarity/Mul}} = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Cosine_Similarity/Tile_2, FD_rotate/concat_49)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dssm.py", line 271, in <module>
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict=feed_dict(True, batch_idx % FLAGS.pack_size))
  File "/home/major/Documents/DSSMStuff/DSSM/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 929, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/major/Documents/DSSMStuff/DSSM/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1152, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/major/Documents/DSSMStuff/DSSM/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1328, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/home/major/Documents/DSSMStuff/DSSM/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1348, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [51000,120] vs. [52224,120]
     [[node Cosine_Similarity/Mul (defined at dssm.py:160)  = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Cosine_Similarity/Tile_2, FD_rotate/concat_49)]]

Caused by op 'Cosine_Similarity/Mul', defined at:
  File "dssm.py", line 160, in <module>
    prod_temp = tf.multiply(prod_first, doc_y)
  File "/home/major/Documents/DSSMStuff/DSSM/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 203, in multiply
    return gen_math_ops.mul(x, y, name)
  File "/home/major/Documents/DSSMStuff/DSSM/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 5042, in mul
    "Mul", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "/home/major/Documents/DSSMStuff/DSSM/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/major/Documents/DSSMStuff/DSSM/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/major/Documents/DSSMStuff/DSSM/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3274, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/major/Documents/DSSMStuff/DSSM/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1770, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [51000,120] vs. [52224,120]
     [[node Cosine_Similarity/Mul (defined at dssm.py:160)  = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Cosine_Similarity/Tile_2, FD_rotate/concat_49)]]
```

From the error messages, one can see that the `tf.multiply` is generating the error, because of the inconsistent shapes of the `tf.tile(query_y, [NEG + 1, 1])` and `doc_y`.

To check the shapes beforehand, I had printed the shapes of both the matrices, and got them to be: [52224, 120] and [52224, 120]. This should not cause an error, right?

Moreover, the error message states that the input shape is actually [51000,120] and [52224, 120].

To try to debug the same, I also put a `try-except` block to catch all the exceptions, but it doesn't catch any exception.

I also tried to put the `try-except` on all the `name_scopes`, and it never caught any exceptions. The only place it is catching the exceptions is where I am initializing the sessions.

**NOTE** I have not uploaded the whole code, because it's way too long, and I don't know if I should do that or not.

[Research Paper Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/cikm2013_DSSM_fullversion.pdf). Please refer to page 3 for the diagram.

Comment: What should I put for `query_y`, `doc_y` and `NEG` in order to reproduce your error?

Comment: You should upload the minimum amount of code for us to copy paste it and reproduce your problem

Comment: `NEG` is just a constant to produce evenly tiled matrices. I have it at 50 right now. Although it still gives an error for any other number. `query_y` is the output of the second layer (I have edited the question to include the model link). It is a matrix of size `batch_size x layer_2_size`. Here my batch size is 1024 and layer 2 desired size, which is 120. `doc_y` is generated by tiling the document matrix by enough number of times, so that their dimensions match.

Comment: @IanQuah that would require me to upload the datafiles. Are you sure, that I have to do that? I will update the code by adding in some more `name_scopes` so that it becomes clear what I am doing.

Comment: Can't you upload a small subset or just a single data point? Also, that's not a mcve and it'll make it harder for people to help